# How can I sort a list of clothing sizes (e.g. 4XL, S, 2XL)?

Tags: java, java-8

I need your help follow query. Given the following List:

```
["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"]
```

How do I sort it so that it is in this order?

["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]

Note that every size is not always present.

Comment: You write code to put them in a list and then sort that list.

Comment: What have you tried to do to make that sort? We are not supposed to do your homework.

Comment: You should use `enum` for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A general approach would focus on the pattern behind the size strings rather than just accom­modating the sample input. You have a fundamental direction denoted by `S`, `M`, or `L` and optional modifiers before it (unless `M`) altering the magnitude.

```
static Pattern SIZE_PATTERN=Pattern.compile("((\\d+)?X)?[LS]|M", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
static int numerical(String size) {
    Matcher m = SIZE_PATTERN.matcher(size);
    if(!m.matches()) throw new IllegalArgumentException(size);
    char c = size.charAt(m.end()-1);
    int n = c == 'S'? -1: c == 'L'? 1: 0;
    if(m.start(1)>=0) n *= 2;
    if(m.start(2)>=0) n *= Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    return n;
}
```

Then, you can sort a list of sizes like

```
List<String> sizes = Arrays.asList("2XL", "5XL", "M", "S", "6XL", "XS", "3XS", "L", "XL");
sizes.sort(Comparator.comparing(Q48298432::numerical));
System.out.print(sizes.toString());
```

where `Q48298432` should be replaced with the name of the class containing the `numerical` method.

Comment: oh darn! thank you! btw I don't think that `12XL` is a valid size at all, I think it's a single digit only, could probably be replaced with `(([2-9])?X)?[LS]|M`

Comment: @Eugene that’s just a way to be future-proof. Just let fast food continue doing its work…

Comment: Haha, hilarious. I am actually using that too. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Build a comparator which does a lookup on your desired order:

```
Comparator<String> sizeOrder = Comparator.comparingInt(desiredOrder::indexOf);
```

where

```
desiredOrder = Arrays.asList("S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL");
```

Then:

```
yourList.sort(sizeOrder);
```

---

If you want, you can build a `Map<String, Integer>` for the lookup:

```
Map<String, Integer> lookup =
    IntStream.range(0, desiredOrder.length())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(desiredOrder::get, i -> i));
```

And then do:

```
Comparator<String> sizeOrder = Comparator.comparing(lookup::get);
```

I'm not convinced that this will be any more performant than using `List.indexOf`, because the `desiredOrder` list is so small.

As with everything performance-related: use the one which you find most readable; profile if you think this is a performance bottleneck, and only *then* try alternatives.

Comment: Also, the `Map` approach will throw if it encounters `Strings` that are not contained in the `desiredOrder` (unless you specify the null-behavior, e.g. with [nullsFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-)), while the `indexOf` - approach silently sorts them to the front (as their index is `-1`).

Comment: @Hulk sure. You could use `s -> checkElementIndex(desiredOrder.indexOf(s), desiredOrder.size())` as the key extractor (for example, using Guava's `Preconditions`) if you wanted that behaviour with the list approach.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using the probably more efficient and certainly clearer `enum` route.

```
// Sizes in sort order.
enum Size {
    SMALL("S"),
    MEDIUM("M"),
    LARGE("L"),
    EXTRA_LARGE("XL"),
    EXTRA2_LARGE("2XL"),
    EXTRA3_LARGE("3XL"),
    EXTRA4_LARGE("4XL"),
    EXTRA5_LARGE("5XL"),
    EXTRA6_LARGE("6XL");
    private final String indicator;

    Size(String indicator) {
        this.indicator = indicator;
    }

    static final Map<String,Size> lookup = Arrays.asList(values()).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    // Key is the indicator.
                    s -> s.indicator,
                    // Value is the size.
                    s-> s));

    public static Size lookup(String s) {
        return lookup.get(s.toUpperCase());
    }

    // Could be improved to handle failed lookups. 
    public static final Comparator<String> sizeOrder = (o1, o2) -> lookup(o1).ordinal() - lookup(o2).ordinal();
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    List<String> test = Arrays.asList("S","6XL", "L");
    Collections.sort(test, Size.sizeOrder);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Comment: Please don't rely on enum ordinals. Someone will come along in 5 years and reorder them and wonder why everything's broken.

Comment: @Michael - FTFY :D

Comment: I still think it's preferable to give each enum instance a "weight" used to sort them. It allows you to have distinct yet equivalent sizes (perhaps Regular and Medium). Plus, y'know, no one actually *reads* comments.

Comment: @Michael agreed. This is exactly the antipattern described in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 31: "Use instance fields instead of ordinals" (Item 35 in 3rd Ed).

Comment: @AndyTurner @Michael - That principle is good when, for example, storing `enum`s in database or using them outside the `enum` in some other way. However, in this instance using the ordinal totally internally to determine the order in the enum is IMHO a perfectly acceptable and tidier solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic algorithm to complete the size sorting. the basic idea of this algorithm is break each parts (`number`, `modifier`, `unit`) of size into the corresponding regions (`[0, 1000)`, `[1000, 1000_000)`, `[1000_000, reset]`), and then use `dir` to decide the direction of the `modifier`. for example:

```
class Size {
  public static int sizeToInt(String size) {
    int n = size.length(), unit = size.charAt(n - 1), dir = unit == 'S' ? 1 : -1;
    //use a separate method to parse the number & extra modifier if needed
    int i = 0;
    int number = n > 1&&Character.isDigit(size.charAt(i)) ? size.charAt(i++) : '1';
    int modifier = i + 1 < n ? size.charAt(i) : 0;
        return -1 * (unit * 1000_000 + dir * (modifier * 1000 + number));
  }
}
```

The solution above is just for the simple case as yours, for the complex case you need to parse `number` & `modifier` and decide how to partition the 
`region`s. Then you can sort sizes by `Comparator` as following code:

```
Comparator<String> sizeComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Size::sizeToInt);

List<String> sizes = Arrays.asList(
    "3XL", "2XL", "XL",
    "5L", "2L", "L",
    "5M", "2M", "M",
    "S", "2S", "3S",
    "XS", "2XS", "3XS"
);


sizes.sort(sizeComparator);

System.out.println(sizes);
//                  ^--- [
//                         "3XS", "2XS", "XS",
//                         "3S", "2S", "S",
//                         "M", "2M", "5M",
//                         "L", "2L", "5L",
//                         "XL", "2XL", "3XL"
//                       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be this:

```
List<String> desiredOrder = Arrays.asList("S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL");
 String [] array = new String[desiredOrder.size()];
   list.forEach(s->{
       if (desiredOrder.indexOf(s) != -1)
             array[desiredOrder.indexOf(s)] = s;
   });

List<String> set= Stream.of(array).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or

```
Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
    list.forEach(s -> {
        if (desiredOrder.indexOf(s) != -1) {
            integers.add(desiredOrder.indexOf(s));
        }
    });

    List<String> sortedItems = integers.stream()
                                       .sorted()
                                       .map(i->desiredOrder.get(i))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This approach would also remove duplicates from `list1` - not sure if that is desired. And it will fail with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case of values that are not contained in `desiredOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Enum class with all the possible sizes and add to it the `getEnum` method to support the sizes that start by number:

```
public enum SizeEnum
{
    S("S"), M("M"), L("L"), XL("XL"), TWO_XL("2XL"), THREE_XL("3XL"), FOUR_XL("4XL"), FIVE_XL("5XL"), SIX_XL("6XL");

    private String value;

    SizeEnum(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static SizeEnum getEnum(String value) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(v -> v.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());
    }
}
```

Use the `SizeEnum` class in the comparator:

```
List<String> sizes = Arrays.asList("2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL");
sizes.sort(Comparator.comparing(v -> SizeEnum.getEnum(v.toUpperCase())));
sizes.stream().forEach(l -> System.out.println(l));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void SortSizes(String [] sizes, String [] sortedRadixArr) throws Exception{
    
    //creating an int array with same length as sortedRadixArr
    //Here each index of intRadix array is mapped to the index of sortedRadixArr
    //Eg:           intRadix = [0,0,0,0,0]  ----> ["S","M","L","XL","2XL"]  

    int [] intRadix = new int[sortedRadixArr.length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++){
        boolean  matchFlag = false;
        for(int j=0; j< sortedRadixArr.length; j++){
            if(sizes[i] == sortedRadixArr[j]){
                //Whenever the String is matched with the String of sortedRadixArr array, 
                //increment the value of intRadix array at the equivalent index of sortedRadixArr.
                //This helps us to count number same strings(sizes). like two or more "S". 
                //We can't do that with sortedRadixArr as it is a String array.
                intRadix[j]++;
                matchFlag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!matchFlag){
            throw new Exception("Invalid size found!");
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < intRadix.length; k++){
        //Loop thru intRadix array. It contains count of respective sizes(Strings) at each index. 
        //We will re-write sizes array in sorted order with help of intRadix as below.
        while(intRadix[k] > 0){
            sizes[count++] = sortedRadixArr[k];
            intRadix[k]--;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here, `sortedRadixArr` is the radix array i.e. values with all possible values:

```
["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]
```

`sizes` is the array that you wanna sort:

```
["2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "L", "M", "S", "XL"]
```

It accepts duplicate values.